# Javascript - Assign an array to a key of another one

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've been checking around for a while but couldn't find anything...at least useful. So here is what I want to accomplish:

```
  a = new Array();
  b = new Array();
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 2;
  b[0] = a;
```

It is not do-able, at least with the way above. How can I do that? Is there any other way to do this? Of course, there are plenty of ways to do what want to do but I want to do this with arrays. ;)

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Humm it all seems to work out just fine ...

Comment: working perfect [see the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hFTAS/)

Comment: The code you posted works, without a character changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and probably should) do something like this instead:

```
var a = [1, 2], 
    b = [a];
```

...or you could do it like this.

```
var a, b /* other vars */;
//other code
b = [(a=[1, 2])];
```

It's generally considered good practice to use the literal syntax when declaring arrays and objects instead of invoking the constructor, so `var foo = [], bar = {};`.

Also, you should use the `var` keyword when defining variables, so they don't leak into the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

Only thing I can think of is declaring the variables a and b, the rest is all valid if you ask me.

```
var a = new Array(),
    b = new Array();

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
b[0] = a;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvELV/

Comment: That's exactly the same as code in question, only difference is `var` keyword, which declares variables in current scope but here it has no effect